# set positive class to 1 in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I'm currently working on preditive models with the 'randomForest' package.

Fitting my model as follow

```
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(10, 3), .combine= combine,  .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
randomForest(bou~.,data=train, trees=50, importance=TRUE)}
```

When using 'confusionMatrix' from the 'caret' package, I've got the results below :

[image]

I'd like to know if it's possible to set the positive class to 1 in the model. I searched in the package description but couldn't find anything about it.

Thank you very much.

Edit : I've found it. It's an option in the 'confusionMatrix' command from the 'caret' package. I was lokking at the wrong place. Here an example if needed.

```
confusionMatrix(predicted,true_values,positive='1')
```

Should I leave my post or delete it ?

Comment: You should create an answer to this question with your solution

Comment: I did as you said, thank you.

Comment: You can also accept your own answer (it's the one that answered your question, so it's acceptable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found it. It's an option in the `confusionMatrix` command from the `caret` package. I was looking at the wrong place. Here an example if needed:

```
confusionMatrix(predicted,true_values,positive='1')
```